# Execute update replace when value does not contain specified value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create query that will replace in all rows (whole column) value to another value if it does not already exist.

Example:

Let's say I have column with values:

```
1. ABC|DEF|GHI|BLA
2. ABC|GHI
3. ABC
4. GHI
4. GHI|JKL
```

And let's say I want to replace `ABC`, `DEF`,`GHI` with one `JKL` value value IF that `JKL` value not exists already. So the result should be:

```
1. JKL|BLA (because I didn't want to replace `BLA`)
2. JKL (because `ABC` AND `GHI` should be replaced with `JKL`)
3. JKL 
4. JKL
4. JKL (because `GHI` should be replaced with `JKL`, but we have already `JKL` value so we just remove `GHI`
```

I have made query that will work, but it is so long:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
            SET COLUMN1 = regexp_replace(COLUMN1, 'ABC|DEF|GHI|(ABC\|DEF\|GHI)|(ABC\|GHI)|(GHI\|JKL)', 'PLS')
```

it will be much longer if for example I will have combination `ABC|JKL` and I will have to add another condition to this query. Could you help me to tune it?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using (the solution for Oracle and Postgres will be very different)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using both DB and need query for both DB.

Comment: You won't get a single query that will work with both databases.

Comment: What if the value in the first row was: `DEF|ABC|GHI|BLA` should the result still be `JKL|BLA`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was not saying the query will be the same. Query I provided works for both - oracle and postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, exactly, I want to replace all values that are not equal to `BLA` (so we should not depend on order)

Comment: What if you replaced each one of ABC DEF GHI with the same JKL _and then_ remove dupes?

Comment: @Fildor hmm that would work :) and propably is the easier that I wanted to :D

Comment: @Fildor hmm but here we have also `|` and the last value should not contian that, only values `inside`

Comment: Horrible design to store data like that.

Comment: @jarlh it's not my idea. Some old approach

Comment: If it is a one time update I would normalize this data (I totally agree with @jarlh) into some proper temporary (not necessarily temporary in exact meaning) tables made updates there and transfer those back to original tables

Comment: I suggest that you append JKL before all values containing the strings to replace first, and then replace these strings with and empty string.   Could you write a stored procedure to process the values and store the groups as separate rows, ie normalise your data while your getting a headache about it?

Comment: @avb it's one time update. It's not my idea how it was designed to store. I just need to replace it, that's all. I would like to avoid some normalizing data as it's not my project.

Comment: @Kendle your idea would work to append if I would know if I should append `JKL|` or `JKL` (if only one value should stay in cell)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it turned out that the order will be always the same, so there won't be an option `DEF|ABC|GHI|BLA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

We start with adding `JKL|`.
`||` is the concatenation on Oracle.
`'(ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL)\|?'` means `ABC` or `DEF` or `GHI` or `JKL` followed by an optional pipe. We remove them (replace with an empty string `''` ). It's simpler to remove `JKL` and add it again than to leave it a deal with duplicates. We have to escape the pipe `\|` because it means OR in regex. `?` means 0 or 1 occurance.
We could develop it further to avoid adding the pipe when they is no other group.
Finally in an outer, second,  regexp_replace we remove a pipe if it is the last character before the end of the string `$`.

> ```
> create table cols(
> column1 VARCHAR (100));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into cols (column1)
> select 'ABC|DEF|GHI|BLA' from dual
> union all
> select 'ABC|GHI' from dual
>  union all
> select 'ABC' from dual
> union all
> select 'GHI' from dual
> union all
> select 'GHI|JKL' from dual
> union all 
> select 'XYZ' from dual;
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> update cols
> set column1 =
>   regexp_replace('JKL|' ||
>   regexp_replace(
>      COLUMN1
>      , '(ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL)\|?','')
>      ,'\|$','')
> where 
> regexp_like(column1, 'ABC|DEF|GHI')
> ```

5 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from cols
> ```
>
> ```
> | COLUMN1 |
> | :------ |
> | JKL|BLA |
> | JKL     |
> | JKL     |
> | JKL     |
> | JKL     |
> | XYZ     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8f63734841f2a45c139d036fbb88290)*

Comment: `||` is the oracle concatenation character, like `&` in Excel of `.` in PHP or `+` in Java to quote a few example. In some flavours of SQL we use `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Please see explanation in the answer. Please accept the answer or upvote if it helps.

Comment: Added second replace to remove final pipes.

Comment: In Postgres Regexp_replace the default function is to only replace the first occurance, we have to add a fourth parameter `'g'` for "global" if want it to replace all occurences.  See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f1c5b7c8989beccb283f57ca1c051d4